# How to determine the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Any ideas on how should I solve this sum?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}$$

Comment: Thank you all for the help. It's very clear now. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series does not pass the basic test that $n$-th term needs to go to zero.

$$
\log n < n
$$
$$
\sqrt[n]{\log n} < \sqrt[n]{n}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}} 
$$

But $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$ converges to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

*Just for reference*

Performing a limit test. 
By [Stolz-Casero](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$$ therefore your limit condenses down to $a_n=1/\log n$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}}$$ You have an indeterminate form of the type $\frac\infty\infty$ so L'Hospital dictates that this is equal to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\log n}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\log(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1/(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$$
Therefore we have an inconclusive test. This means we should perform either a comparison or integral test. I have made this community wiki and it exists for informative reasons.

Comment: Does the Stolz–Cesàro theorem imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$? Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Notice for $n \geq 2$ $$ n > ( \log(n) )^{\frac{1}{n}} \iff \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{( \log(n) )^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

If you dont believe the first inequality, it follows easily from the following facts:

$$ n^n > n $$

This is obvious for $n \geq 2 $.

Next, since $e^n \geq n +1 $, then $n \geq \log(n+1)  \implies n - 1 \geq \log (n) \implies n \geq \log(n) + 1 > \log(n) $

Now, by transitivity,

$$ n^n > \log (n) \implies n > \log(n) )^{\frac{1}{n}} $$